# branch cut for complex logarithm involving composition with a square root

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

Here is the problem I am working on:

PROBLEM: Let $f(z) = \log(z+(z^2-1)^{1/2})$. The branch cut for $(z^2 - 1)^{1/2}$ is to be the portion of the real axis $[-1,1]$.

(a) Show that $(z^2 - 1)^{1/2}$ is analytic for all values $z \in \mathbb{C}$ not on the branch cut.

(b) For the transformation $w = z + (z^2 - 1)^{1/2}$, determine the branch for for $f(w)$.

SOLUTION: For part (a) we consider the function 
$$h(z) = \exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\int_{z_0}^z\left(\frac{1}{s-1} + \frac{1}{s+1}\right)ds\right),$$
where $z_0 \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ and the integral is taken over any piecewise smooth contour contained in $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$. The integral above is multivalued because closed loop integrals can contain the singularities at $\pm 1$. Note however that given any closed curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ the winding number $W(\gamma,1) = W(\gamma,-1)$, and so it is clear that the integral 
$$\int_{z_0}^z\left(\frac{1}{s-1} + \frac{1}{s+1}\right)ds$$
over two different paths can differ only by an integer multiple of $4\pi i$. Thus, the function $h$ is well defined because $\exp(2k\pi i) = 1$ for any integer $k$. Since the integral in the definition of $h$ has a well defined local primitive it then follows that $h$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ with 
$$h'(z) = h(z)\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1}\right) = h(z) \frac{z}{z^2 - 1}.$$
It then follows that 
$$\frac{d}{dz} \left(\frac{h^2}{z^2-1}\right) = 0$$
in $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$, and hence since $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ is connected we have that 
$$h^2(z) = C(z^2 - 1)$$
for some constant $C$. Adding an appropriate constant to the definition of $h$ yields a branch of the square root in $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$.

(b) I am not sure how to approach part (b), or even what the spirit of the problem is really. It seems like we are being asked to define a branch of $\log(g(g(z))$, where $g(z) = z + (z^2 - 1)^{1/2}$. Thus, we can define the needed branch of the logarithm if we find a simply connected set where $g \circ g (z)$ is nonzero. Any suggestions?

Comment: In the $w$-plane, there are branch points at $w=0$ and $w=\infty$.  Given $w=z+\sqrt{z^2-1}$, what is the image of the pair of branch points in the $z$-plane?  That is to ask, for what value(s) of $z$ does $z+\sqrt{z^2-1}=0$?

Comment: I am confused by your answer. When you say the "branch points in the $w$ plane.." with respect to what function are you referring to? It seems to me that $z+ \sqrt{z^2 - 1}$ is never zero. If this is true then we should be able to define the desired logarithm with the branch cut being $(-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)$. This branch cut leaves us with a simply connected domain on which $g(z) = z + \sqrt{z^2 -1 }$ is holomorphic and $g(g(z))$ is never zero.

Comment: Well done.  You have it.

Comment: Actually we need to be a bit more careful I think. We need to check also that $g(\mathbb{C} \setminus ((-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty))) \cap ((-\infty,-1] \cup [1,\infty)) = \emptyset.$